# How to transform Bytestring to Source[Bytestring, Any]

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http, reactive-kafka

I'm receiving a file as a Bytestring from Kafka Reactive Streams consumer; I want to construct an akka-http request with this Bytestring as an entity HttpEntity.Default. HttpEntity.Default requires Source[Bytestring, Any] as one of its parameters.

What is a best way to connect the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Source.single`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.stream.javadsl.Source$@single[T](element:T):akka.stream.javadsl.Source[T,akka.NotUsed]):

```
HttpEntity.Default(
  ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`,
  byteString.size,
  Source.single(byteString)
)
```

That said, are you really sure you need exactly `HttpEntity.Default`? You can use the [`HttpEntity.apply(ContentType, ByteString)`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity$@apply(contentType:akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType,data:akka.util.ByteString):akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Strict) method to construct an entity directly out of a `ByteString`:

```
HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, byteString)
```

It returns an instance of [`HttpEntity.Strict`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity$$Strict.html) instead of `HttpEntity.Default`, but `Strict` can be used for sending HTTP requests just fine.

Comment: Thank you, this will definitely work. Is there away I can extract Source[Bytestring] from Kafka consumer client so that I can chain the stream from Kafka to Akka-http: because now I load entire Bytestring in memory and then do an akka-http request?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know because I never used Kafka. But I suspect it is possible, at least, I see something very like it [in reactive-kafka](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/consumer.html#connecting-producer-and-consumer) docs. You probably should ask another question about it.

Comment: Im using HttpEntity.Default because the file size is known